# Error loading R dev_mode from .Rprofile

Tags: r, devtools, dev-mode

I'm doing a lot of development in R at the moment, so I would like to enable dev_mode when R starts up.

I've tried adding `dev_mode()` to my .Rprofile, given here:

```
library("devtools")
library("testthat")

dev_mode()
```

But doing so gives the following error:

`Error in is_library(path) : could not find function "file_test"`

and dev_mode isn't loaded on startup. Would anyone know how to fix this?

R 2.15.1-2, devtools 1.0, testthat 0.7

Comment: Works for me. R 2.15.1, devtools 0.8.0.99, testthat 0.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file_test` comes from the `utils` package, so maybe that's not getting loaded. Try:

```
library(utils)
```

before anything else in your `.Rprofile`.

As commented, this works for me without it... YMMV...